# Fade away blogspot site title and site-description after a few seconds

Tags: jquery

I added this code and it works fine. But it started affecting other things that stopped working properly. Is there a mistake in the following code?

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function()
{$("h1").fadeTo(4000,0);});
</script>
```

Comment: What things where affected? Be more specific.

Comment: No, there is no mistake, code affects just h1 element. As long as you have just one h1 tag in HTML (and you should) there shouldn't be problems...

Comment: you really have to be more specific about things affected

Comment: SORRY! I put a detailed explanation here http://railingstoronto.blogspot.com/2015/06/explanation.html   I am not a PRO and will appreciate any explanation

Comment: I added even more details. See the page above. @Nelson

Comment: What was you expecting this code to do ?

Comment: I tried to fade away blogspot site-title and hide blogspot site-description after a few seconds. I could not do it this way and have found another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my particular blogger blog and for some reason this `<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'/>` interfered with other elements of my blogspot. And its removal disabled the fading effect.

After trying this and that I have found a different solution for my particular case.

I used animation to fade away blogspot site-title and hide blogspot site-description after a few seconds.

```
.site-title a {
font: bold 36px/36px 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 36px 0 14px 40px;
float: left;
color: #fff;
background-color: black !important;padding: 8px;
animation-name: example22;
animation-duration: 10s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.site-description {
clear: both;
font: bold 20px/20px 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0 0 0 40px;
color: #fff;
background-color: black; width: 423px;padding: 8px;
animation-name: example22;
animation-duration: 10s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

@keyframes example22 {
    from {background-color: black;}
    to {background-color: transparent;}
    from {color: #fff;}
    to {color: transparent;}
}
```

I am not a PRO and this could be bad or wrong. So be careful, even though it works perfectly on my blogspot

good luck

Answer (score 0):

As per your question:

> I added this code and it works fine. But it started affecting other
>   things that stopped working properly. Is there a mistake in the
>   following code?

You said you **added** this code, where did you add it? Without more code or explanation it's pretty hard to tackle down whats going wrong (if there is anything at all going wrong).

The things I can think of, is that you have more than one `<h1></h1>` tags in your page and the code will affect all of them and you wanted to only affect the first one. On the other hand, if you added that code after another jquery script tag (maybe jquery was loaded in the header, and then you added it a second time with this code?) there is the possibility that you are overriding jquery and loosing customs plugins.

Other than this, without code, there is not much to say about this.

You are adding jquery lib twice, and it seems that you are loosing some plugins added to it. Remove the following line:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'/>
```

Comment: SORRY!  I put a detailed explanation here http://railingstoronto.blogspot.com/2015/06/explanation.html   I am not a PRO and will appreciate any help

Comment: I removed  `<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'/>`  fading stopped working, but sub-menu began working


mb it conflicts with two other `<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>` and `<script src='//www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'/>`

(I do not understand this stuff)